# Upper bound on second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, curvature, submanifold

Consider a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $V$ and $W$ be two vector fields on $\mathcal{M}$.

As usual, we define the second fundamental form to be $ \mathrm{I\!I}(V, W) = (\tilde{\nabla}_V (W))^\perp $, where $\tilde{\nabla}$ is the ambient covariant derivative and $X^\perp$ represents the normal projection of $X$.

I am interested in bounding $\| \mathrm{I\!I}(V, W) \|$ in terms of the bounds on the norms of $V$ and $W$.

For example, when the manifold is the sphere with the usual inherited metric, assuming that for all $x$ it holds that $\| V(x) \| \leq \alpha $ and $\| W(X) \| \leq \beta $, I believe we have $\| \mathrm{I\!I}(V, W) \| \leq \alpha \beta $.

In general, I would expect such a bound to also depend on the curvature of the manifold.

*Later edit*: when $\mathcal{M}$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^d$, letting $N$ be a smooth normal vector field, I know that
$ \| \mathrm{I\!I}(V, W) \| =  \lvert \langle N, \mathrm{I\!I}(V, W) \rangle \rvert = \lvert h(V, W) \rvert $, where $h$ is the scalar second fundamental form. In this case, the principal curvatures $\mathcal{k}_i$ are defined as the eigenalues of the shape operator $s : T_x \mathcal{M} \rightarrow T_x \mathcal{M}$, $s = W_N$, where $W_N$ is the Weingarten map in direction $N$. We can write $h(V, W)$ in the basis of $T_x \mathcal{M}$ given by the eigenvectors $b_i$ of $s$ (with corresponding eigenvalue $\mathcal{k}_i$) to obtain

$$ h(V, W) = \langle W, sV \rangle = \langle W, s \sum_i \langle V, b_i \rangle b_i \rangle = \sum_i \mathcal{k}_i \langle V, b_i \rangle \langle W, b_i \rangle $$

From here, it's easy to obtain a bound on $\lvert h(V, W) \rvert$ in terms of the maximum principal curvature.

The question would be how to extend this for the case when $\mathcal{M}$ is an arbitrary smooth manifold. I know, for example, that the second fundamental form is related to the Riemann curvature tensor through the Gauss Equation (in Lee's Riemannian manifolds, Theorem 8.5), but it's not clear how to proceed from there. I am willing to assume I have bounds on (any sort of) curvature that comes up.

Any pointers on how I could proceed for obtaining such a bound in the general case are appreciated!

Comment: Of course you need to know the extrinsic curvature of the manifold. Dependence on the norms of $V$ and $W$ is the easy part.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Could you share some references on how to proceed?

Comment: Your question is way too vague/broad. Can you do it explicitly for a surface in $\Bbb R^3$? What about a hypersurface in $\Bbb R^d$? Then you will get the maximum eigenvalues of $\mathbf{II}$, i.e., the maximum principal curvatures. But of course we cannot hope to know what those are without a lot more information.

Comment: Yes, I know how the second fundamental form is related to the principal curvatures of a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^d$, I updated my question to include that. (I should have done this from the beginning, sorry).

Comment: The estimate cited by both Ted Shifrin and Mikhail Katz and now added to your question is the best you can do. You cannot bound the eigenvalue with maximum magnitude of the second fundamental form (i.e., the principal curvature with maximum magnitude) by the intrinsic curvature tensor.

Comment: Thank you for the details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in the case of surfaces, it is hopeless to obtain bounds purely in terms of the Gaussian curvature.  This can be seen from the example of a thin tube.  The Gaussian curvature is zero, but the second fundamental form can be arbitrarily large.  You mention that one can obtain bounds in terms of the principal curvatures.  Note that no intrinsic invariants would capture those, and therefore looking for bounds in terms of intrinsic invariants is hopeless.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I agree that one needs to extrinsic curvature, but I am perfectly fine with that.

Comment: @AndreeaM, if so, then the bound is the maximal eigenvalue of the second fundamental form, as pointed out in the *comments*.

Comment: Thank you for your input!